# Write Sum of Matrices Explicitly

Tags: linear-algebra

I have sum of lots of matrices A+B+C+D+E+... and I want that Mathematica shows me this as explicit matrix sum, i.e.

Explicit Matrix A + Explicit Matrix B + Explicit Matrix C + ....

and not just the result of this sum. Is there any way to tell Mathematica that I want the explicit sum instead of the result?

*(My sum yields a wrong result and I want to check which term is troublesome)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe

```
m1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
m2 = m1*10;
m3 = m1/10;

(plus = Inactivate[m1 + m2 + m3, Plus]) /. a_List :> MatrixForm@a
```

[image]

```
Activate@plus
```

[image]

Comment: +1 ... BTW, ain't that `Activate`/`Inactivate` a fresh 10.0 addition? How would one do it in older version? AFAIR, `Hold` was used for it?

Comment: @vaxquis, take a look below, it might help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pre-V10 version, which also works in V10 of course:

```
m1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
m2 = m1*10;
m3 = m1/10;

Block[{Plus}, HoldForm @@ {m1 + m2 + m3}]
(*  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} + {{10, 20}, {30, 40}} + {{1/10, 1/5}, {3/10, 2/5}}  *)
```

I don't usually use `MatrixForm`, except perhaps when printing out a notebook for someone else to read, which I never do.  But for fans, this will prettyprint it:

```
Map[MatrixForm, %, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I might add a suggestion in response to this piece of contextual information:

> *(My sum yields a wrong result and I want to check which term is troublesome)*

I don't know where or how in the OP's code the list of matrices is generated, but if there is a line of code that adds them up with `Plus`, then duplicating the line and modifying one of them, with just a little typing as follows, can store the list of matrices:

```
sum = A + B + ...
Block[{Plus = List}, foo = A + B +...]
```

Then `foo` will contain the list of your matrices, which you can examine one-by-one `foo[[1]]`, `foo[[2]]`, etc. (or in a loop or whatever).  I'm assuming it's not a very large list, because inspecting the `Plus` expression would be unmanageable if it were.

If the code is very complicated and you're worried about leaving such debugging lines lying around, you could add

```
If[TrueQ@ debugQ, Block[{Plus = List}, foo = A + B +...]]
```

where `debugQ` is a global variable you would set `debugQ = True` only when debugging.  If it is unset or set to `False`, there is little overhead in having the extra line in the code.

If you don't like having the extra variable `debugQ` in the  `` Global` `` context, you can put it in an unlikely-to-cause-trouble context by calling it `` tmp`debugQ `` or perhaps `` Private`debugQ `` and so forth.